# Metric on half-open interval s.t. subset is open w.r.t. $d$ iff open w.r.t. Euclidean metric

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

I wish to find a metric $d$ on the space $X = (0,1]$ such that $(X,d)$ is complete and so that a subset of $X$ is open with respect to $d$ if and only if it is open with respect to the Euclidean metric on $X$.

Any help / thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean you want a subset $U\subseteq X$ to be open iff it is open as $U\subset \Bbb R$? I don't think that can be done, seing as any ball containing $1$ would be non-open in the real line.

Answer (score 1):

A generalized version of this question has been discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7578/two-metrics-induce-the-same-topology-but-one-is-complete-and-the-other-isnt). I think the 2nd answer on the page is related to your question.